# Swift: How to take a screenshot of only half of the view?

Tags: ios, screenshot, viewcontroller

I am trying to take a screenshot (after a button press) of only half of the viewController size (positioned right in the middle).

I know that I can take a screenshot of the whole view like this:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, true, 0.0)
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I have looked through stackoverflow, but it still doesn't work.

This for instance doesn't work with these error messages:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(100, 100), false, 0);
```

Error: **Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads**

```
self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRect(-50,-5-,view.bounds.size.width,view.bounds.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

Error: **Argument labels '(_:, _:, _:, _:)' do not match any available overloads**

```
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

How can I create a screenshot of exactly half of the viewController?

Comment: `CGRectMake` have been renamed to `CGRect(x: , y: , width: , height: )`

Comment: Thanks. I hav edited the question, now I get the error that Argument labels '(_:, _:, _:, _:)' do not match any available overloads.

Comment: You will need to write the variable name like `x: -50, y:-5`.... also

Answer (score 0):

**Try This.For Swift**

```
extension UIView {

    func screenshot() -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size).image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: bounds.size.width/2.0, height: bounds.size.height/2.0)), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }

}
```

**Use.**

```
let image = view.screenshot()
```